# Change the grid size to match the size of the boxes in the grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a visual grid of 20x20 using matplotlib. however I am having trouble adjusting the size of the grid to fit the size of each box.

here is my code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np

grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
    ]

print (grid)

zvals = grid

# make a color map of fixed colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white','black'])
bounds=[-2,-1,1,2]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# tell imshow about color map so that only set colors are used
img = pyplot.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest',
                    cmap = cmap,norm=norm)

# make a color bar
pyplot.colorbar(img,cmap=cmap,
                norm=norm,boundaries=bounds,ticks=[0,1])

pyplot.grid(which= 'both')

pyplot.show()
```

I want the grid to be the size of black boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this part to your code:

```
ax = pyplot.gca()
major_ticks = np.arange(0.5, 20, 1)
pyplolt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.grid(which='both')
pyplot.grid(True)
```

Output:

[image]

Ps. usually `pyplot` is imported in this way: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`